# Make UITableViewCell expand when text exceeds space

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, text, expand

I have a `UITableViewCell` and it is `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. When I try to put text longer than the `UITableViewCell`, it truncates it. How do I make the cell expand to accommodate this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not expand cell's width more than iphone's screen... What you can do is 
1> make font smaller
2> make your text multiple lines

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(80.0, 0.0, 240, 40);
    UILabel *textView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentRect];

    textView.text = mytext;
    textView.numberOfLines = 2;
    textView.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to do exactly what you're trying to do, but it would probably go something like this:

You need to change the size of a view depending on the length of the text string inside it.

The table view delegate (your view controller) should implement

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Message *msg = (Message *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [[msg text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:kLabelFontSize]
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220.0f, 480.0f)
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    CGFloat minHeight = 20.0f;
    CGFloat height = size.height > minHeight ? size.height : minHeight;
    return height;
}
```

which tells the view how tall to make each row.

You're going to need to need to also resize the UITableViewCell label's frame similarly.

Comment: i really like this solution.  you can simply return any float to easily change the height of the cell.  very easy

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the cells need to be the same height and width. You can change the height of the `UITableViewCells` using the `tableView's rowHeight` property.

For example, if you subclass `UITableViewController`

`self.tableView.rowHeight = 100;`

Another option is to add a custom `UILabel` as a subview of the cells contentView like shown earlier.